# Parse XML to DataFrame with multiple elements

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to parse XML with multiple subelements.
I have the following XML file:

```
<Fruits>
    <Fruit ReferenceDate="2022-09-22"
                FruitName="Apple">
        <Identifier FruitIdentifier="111"
                    FruitBrand="GoldenApple"/>
        <FruitInformation Country="Turkey"
                          Colour="Green"/>
        <CompanyInformation CompanyName="GlobalFruits"
                            Location="USA"/>
        <Languages>
            <LanguageDependent CountryId="GB"
                               LanguageId="EN">
                <FreeText1>Sample sentence 1.</FreeText1>
                <FreeText2>Sample sentence 2.</FreeText2>
            </LanguageDependent>
            <LanguageDependent CountryId="FI"
                               LanguageId="FI">
                <FreeText1>Sample sentence 3.</FreeText1>
                <FreeText2>Sample sentence 4.</FreeText2>
            </LanguageDependent>
        </Languages>
        <CompanyLanguages>
            <CompanyLanguage LName="English"
                             Identity="EN333"/>
            <CompanyLanguage LName="Norwegian"
                             Identity="NO444"/>
        </CompanyLanguages>     
    </Fruit>
    <Fruit ReferenceDate="2022-09-22"
                FruitName="Orange">
        <Identifier FruitIdentifier="222"
                    FruitBrand="BestOrange"/>
        <FruitInformation Country="Egypt"
                          Colour="Orange"/>
        <CompanyInformation CompanyName="FreshFood"
                            Location="UK"/>
        <Languages>
            <LanguageDependent CountryId="GB"
                               LanguageId="EN">
                <FreeText1>Sample sentence 5.</FreeText1>
                <FreeText2>Sample sentence 6.</FreeText2>
            </LanguageDependent>
            <LanguageDependent CountryId="SV"
                               LanguageId="SE">
                <FreeText1>Sample sentence 7.</FreeText1>
                <FreeText2>Sample sentence 8.</FreeText2>
            </LanguageDependent>
        </Languages>
        <CompanyLanguages>
            <CompanyLanguage LName="Swedish"
                             Identity="SV111"/>
            <CompanyLanguage LName="Finnish"
                             Identity="FI222"/>
        </CompanyLanguages> 
    </Fruit>
</Fruits>
```

**Issue:** I want to receive 4 rows for each "Fruit" element (8 rows in total) from the XML provided above. My current solution returns only 1 row per each "Fruit" element.
Please find below my current code and output and the desired output:
**My current code:**

```
import pandas as pd 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xtree = ET.parse("fruits.xml")
xroot = xtree.getroot() 

rows = []

for f in xroot.findall('.//Fruit'):
    ReferenceDate = f.attrib.get("ReferenceDate")
    FruitName = f.attrib.get("FruitName")
    FruitIdentifier = f.find("Identifier").attrib.get("FruitIdentifier")
    FruitBrand = f.find("Identifier").attrib.get("FruitBrand")
    Country = f.find("FruitInformation").attrib.get("Country")
    Colour = f.find("FruitInformation").attrib.get("Colour")
    CompanyName = f.find("CompanyInformation").attrib.get("CompanyName")
    Location = f.find("CompanyInformation").attrib.get("Location")
    CountryId = f.find(".//LanguageDependent").attrib.get("CountryId")
    LanguageId = f.find(".//LanguageDependent").attrib.get("LanguageId")
    FreeText1 = f.find(".//LanguageDependent/FreeText1").text
    FreeText2 = f.find(".//LanguageDependent/FreeText2").text
    Language = f.find(".//CompanyLanguage").attrib.get("LName")
    Identity = f.find(".//CompanyLanguage").attrib.get("Identity")

    rows.append({"ReferenceDate": ReferenceDate
                 , "FruitName": FruitName
                 , "FruitIdentifier": FruitIdentifier
                 , "FruitBrand": FruitBrand
                 , "Country": Country
                 , "Colour": Colour
                 , "CompanyName": CompanyName
                 , "Location": Location
                 , "CountryId": CountryId
                 , "LanguageId": LanguageId
                 , "FreeText1": FreeText1
                 , "FreeText2": FreeText2
                 , "Language": Language
                 , "Identity": Identity
                 })

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
print(df)
df.to_csv('test.csv', sep='|')
```

**Current output:**
[image]

**Desired output**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In each node that have more than one children you need to loop again.

Here I mention a simple version of solution, all nodes are not included, but I am pretty sure you can get the idea.

```py
for f in xroot.findall('.//Fruit'):
    # add and change key value based on your need
    temp = {"t1":[], "t2":[], "t3":[]} 
    # loop back and forth in each loop
    for i in f.findall('.//Languages'):
        for j in i.findall('.//LanguageDependent'):
            for t1 in i.findall('.//FreeText1'):
                temp["t1"].append(t1.text)
            for t2 in i.findall('.//FreeText2'):
                temp["t2"].append(t2.text)
    for t3 in f.findall(".//Identifier"):
        temp["t3"].append(t3.attrib.get("FruitIdentifier"))
        # ....
    # rows.append(temp)
```